# SVG with height 100% will never shrink below 150px

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I'm trying to create a SVG which stretches (in height) to a paragraph with variable height next to it.

Currently I have the following working example code which works as long if the paragraph is bigger then 150px. As soon as the paragraph is less in height, the SVG stops shrinking.

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <svg style="display:block;width: 40px;height:100%">
      <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="100%" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 300px;border:1px solid">
    This paragraph is 300px, the svg will stretch accordingly
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <svg style="width: 40px;height:100%">
      <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="100%" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 50px;border:1px solid">
    This paragraph is 50px, the svg will not shrink below 150px
  </div>
</div>
```

This can't be solved with javascript, it should be responsive. the SVG is in practice a lot more complicated and cannot be replaced with a simple `border-left: 1px solid black`

Comment: did you try to add viewBox ?

Comment: Yes I tried adding `viewbox="0 0 40 100%"` but it didn't helpt

Comment: the 100% is somehow the issue, but I don't know exactly

Comment: I'm aware of that. But it's the only way I know how to make this SVG responsive (without using any javascript)

Comment: Percentages are invalid in a viewBox

Comment: Have you tried 100vh as opposed to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set your `viewBox` accordingly, I do not know the `userSpaceOnUse` (min x min y width height) of your SVG, let's say `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`.
- Remove `width` and `height` attributes.
- Set the style attribute to 100% width and 100% height.
- override the default `xMidYMid` value by setting `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

Resulting svg should look like this:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

SVGs like other replaced elements have a default size of 300x150.  If they don't have enough information to calculate their width or height, they will report their default width (300) or height (150)

For your first example div, when the browser is trying to calculate its height, it will ask the first child what its height is. It will report a default of 150px (from the SVG). The second child will report 300px.  So the browser will set that first div to 300px. This is the greater of its two children.

In the second div, the same process will be followed.  This time the max height will be the default height of the SVG (150px) since that is larger than the other child (50px).  So that section will end up at a height of 150px.

To fix this, you don't have much choice other than giving the SVG a specific height, rather than using a percentage.

```
<svg style="width: 40px; height:50px">
```

Demo:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <svg style="display:block;width: 40px;height:100%">
      <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="100%" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 300px;border:1px solid">
    This paragraph is 300px, the svg will stretch accordingly
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <svg style="width: 40px; height:50px">
      <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="100%" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 50px;border:1px solid">
    This paragraph is 50px, the svg will not shrink below 150px
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example has a different setup from yours, but it still addresses the issue of the SVG not shrinking below 150px:

The html...

```
    <div class='parent'>
      <svg class='my-svg'>
        <rect class='my-rect'></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

And the css...

```
.my-rect {
  fill: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

You can play with the working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/k93rLvzg/98/

The key is the absolutely positioned `div` element housing the SVG. The SVG will shrink below 150px if the parent also is below 150px.

I actually don't know the reason for this, and it'd be great if someone could explain it.